# The location of the preference file of LyX in kubuntu?

Tags: color, lyx, themes

I have managed to install a new color scheme in my LyX on kubuntu system, according to [Tips from LyX wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ColorSchemes), I need to copy and paste some text into the file "preferences". However, I didn't found that file under the `~/.lyx` directory.

Here is the files in the ~/.lyx directory:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct directory. There currently is no "preferences" file because you currently don't have any custom preferences. If you change a preference in LyX and save it, a "preferences" file will be created.

First, you do not need to change preferences in LyX. If the file does not exist, you can just create it. But if you prefer for LyX to create it, go to Tools > Preferences, and change any setting. For example, go to Look & Feel  > Screen Fonts and and increase it by 1. Then click on "Save" (note: do not click on "Apply", which only applies it temporarily for the current session, not permanently).

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you give more details, like how to "change a preference"?

Comment: I added notes on how to change preferences in LyX.